# Display image in image view in android application

Tags: android, json

I got json data in this way:

```
{"data":[{"img_name":"abc.jpeg","img_path":"6"}]}
```

Now How can I display this image in image view in my android application.Please help me to solve.

Comment: where is the image? local, network?

Comment: Use imageloader https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-listview-with-images-using-recyclerview-and-volley/

Comment: Post some details....

Comment: Image is saved in local server

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing? Show the code you have done.

Comment: I can able to display image if I have complete path of image(http://xxx.xxx.x.x/image/abc.jpeg) using imageloader ,But for this type json result, am not getting how to display the image. What is the way to load image if I have this type of Json result?

Comment: We cannot help you to figure out what is the server address. Maybe you can find it in the API documentation that your are ussing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want.

First you need to parse the `JSON` and get the `img_path` and `img_name`. Then you can create the url of the image. The url generation logic depends on your server logic.

Something like this,

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(your_json_data);
String img_path = data.getString("img_path");
String img_name = data.getString("img_name");

String url = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/" + img_path + "/" + img_name;
```

Use an imageloader like Picasso to load the image.

Comment: Thank you so much.Almost same.Here am using url http://xxx.xxx.x.ximage.php. When I run this code I am getting that Json result.Where Should I write this php path to display the image?

Comment: Use a temporary variable like `url` variable shown in above code.

Comment: I got it.Thank you so much :)